# Template engine used by phpfox 3

Tags: php, oop, templates, model-view-controller, phpfox

can anyone kindly tell me the template engine used by Phpfox 3 social network engine or a possible link to a tutorial that explains the template. I would also be happy to get in touch with great resources that teaches Phpfox

Answer (score 0):

Phpfox script uses some template tags that resemble the Smarty template engine. This doesnt mean that phpfox uses Smarty, we have our own template engine and do not use Smarty in any part of our script.
So, if you are a developer or designer and are wondering what templates are available here is a list that I hope you will find useful. Please remember that some of the tags require a template variable, like when you assign() to the template in the controller.

All supported function is listed in this file:

> PF.Base\include\library\phpfox\template\cache.class.php function Phpfox_Template_Cache::_parseFunction()

This is some of example.

```html
// HTML
this is a funky pointer -{ldelim}
// Code Gererated
this is a funky pointer -{
 
// HTML
This next is php {php} echo 'hello'; {/php}
// Code Gererated
This next is php <?php echo 'hello'; ?>
 
 
 
// HTML
I can count to 5: {for $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++} {$i} {/for}
// Output Gererated
I can count to 5: 12345
 
// HTML
My numbers are {foreach from=$aVar item=iItem} {$iItem},
// Output Gererated
My numbers are 1,2,3,4,
 
 
 
// HTML
Show the ajax loading image {img theme='ajax/small.gif'}
 
// HTML Example Show an image uploaded by a user
{img server_id=$aPhoto.server_id path='photo.url_photo' file=$aPhoto.destination suffix='_150' max_width=150 max_height=150 class="hover_action" title=$aPhoto.title}
```